# Method Out of Range error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

This code is trying to print just one worksheet called NQLD Print, then cycle through all the options in a data validation list in cell B2 on that worksheet:

```
Sub PrintAll()

Dim strValidationRange As String
Dim rngValidation As Range
 On Error GoTo errhandler
Dim rngDepartment As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If (sh.Name = "NQLD PRINT") Then

      ' Turn off screen updating
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
          ' Identify the source list of the data validation
             strValidationRange = Range("B2").Validation.Formula1
           Set rngValidation = Range(strValidationRange)
            ' Set the value in the selection cell to each selection in turn
            ' and print the results.

            For Each rngDepartment In rngValidation.Cells
            Range("B2").Value = rngDepartment.Value
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut

            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   Exit Sub

errhandler: MsgBox Err.Description

End If

 Next

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error *Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed*.

Answer (score 0):

Cycling through the worksheets does not automatically confer parentage to cell ranges referenced within the worksheets.

Reference `sh` for each worksheet's ranges.

```
strValidationRange = sh.Range("B2").Validation.Formula1
Set rngValidation = sh.Range(strValidationRange)
```

Alternately, use a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx).

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With sh
        If (.Name = "NQLD PRINT") Then
            ' Turn off screen updating
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ' Identify the source list of the data validation
             strValidationRange = .Range("B2").Validation.Formula1
             Set rngValidation = .Range(strValidationRange)

             ' more stuff here
         End If
    Next sh
```

Note the `.Name` and `.Range` and not `sh.Name` and `Range`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place "sh." as a prefix to every occurrence of Range().